# Label each one of the different graphs generated by a parameter

Tags: plotting, graphics

I need help with this. I want to label each one of the graphs generated by the values of the parameter t, but I'm unable to do it because the program takes the five graphs of the summatory with a parameter as one. I've already generated the graphs I desired, but labeling is just impossible for me. Could you please help me? Or what could be an option for what I want?

Here is the code:

```
Plot[Evaluate[{100, (200/Pi) \!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(n = 1\), \(9\)]\((\((\((1 - 
\*SuperscriptBox[\((\(-1\))\), \(n\)])\)/n)\) Exp[\(-\((
\*SuperscriptBox[\(n\), \(2\)])\)\) t] Sin[n*x])\)\) /. 
    t -> {0.05, 0.35, 0.6, 1, 1.5}}, {x, 0, Pi}], 
 PlotLegend -> {"t=0", "t=0.05", "t=0.35", "t=0.6", "t=1", "t=1.5"} , 
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "u"}, 
 PlotStyle -> {{Thick, Black}, {Thick, Cyan}, {Thick, 
    Magenta}, {Thick, Yellow}, {Thick, Orange}, {Thick, Green}}]
```

An image of what appears:

[image]

Comment: Please post your Mathematica code here,not the picture.

Comment: If you have version 9.0 or newer,  replace `PlotLegend` with `PlotLegends` in your code.

Comment: I don't have it. I have the 8.0. Is there any form to do what I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Needs["PlotLegends`"]

Plot[Evaluate[ Join[{100}, (200/Pi) \!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(n = 1\), \(9\)]\((\((\((1 - 
\*SuperscriptBox[\((\(-1\))\), \(n\)])\)/n)\) Exp[\(-\((
\*SuperscriptBox[\(n\), \(2\)])\)\) t] Sin[n*x])\)\) /. 
       t -> {0.05, 0.35, 0.6, 1, 1.5}]], {x, 0, Pi}, 
  PlotLegend -> {"t=0", "t=0.05", "t=0.35", "t=0.6", "t=1", "t=1.5"} , 
  AxesLabel -> {"x", "u"}, 
  PlotStyle -> {{Thick, Black}, {Thick, Cyan}, {Thick, 
        Magenta}, {Thick, Yellow}, {Thick, Orange}, {Thick, Green}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, you're amazing! Thank you so much, really. :D

Answer (score 0):

Use `Epilog->{Text[` commands `]}`. As below:

`Plot[Evaluate[{100, (200/Pi) \!\( \*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(n = 1\), \(9\)]\((\((\((1 -  \*SuperscriptBox[\((\(-1\))\), \(n\)])\)/n)\) Exp[\(-\(( \*SuperscriptBox[\(n\), \(2\)])\)\) t] Sin[n*x])\)\) /.  t -> {0.05, 0.35, 0.6, 1, 1.5}}, {x, 0, Pi}],  AxesLabel -> {"x", "u"}, PlotStyle -> {{Thick, Black}, {Thick, Cyan}, {Thick, Magenta}, {Thick, Yellow}, {Thick, Orange}, {Thick, Green}}, Epilog -> {Text["0.05", {2.8, 85}], Text["0.35", {2.5, 70}]}]`

[image]